# Pressing Enter to Continue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, enter

I have a JDialog which has two fields, username and password. I want to make the form like normal ones in which pressing enter will be like pressing continue.

I have already tried `getRootPane().setDefaultButton(myButton);`, but only that does not seem to work.

Comment: for better help sooner edit you question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have already tried getRootPane().setDefaultButton(myButton);, but only that does not seem to work.

than you have to invoke code for this button with method

[JButton#doClick();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29)

but better would be use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private Timer timer1;
    private JButton killkButton = new JButton("Kill JDialog");
    private JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");

    public Test() {
        contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
        buttonPane.add(okButton);
        killkButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        killkButton.setActionCommand("Kill JDialog");
        buttonPane.add(killkButton);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                startTimer();
            }

            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }
        });
        dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dialog.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        dialog.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        dialog.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocation(100, 100);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        setKeyBindings();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings() {
        okButton.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "clickENTER");
        okButton.getActionMap().put("clickENTER", new AbstractAction() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.setVisible(false);
                startTimer();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        timer1 = new Timer(1000, new AbstractAction() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dialog.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        timer1.setDelay(500);
        timer1.setRepeats(false);
        timer1.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test test = new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JButton button = ...
JTextField password = ...
ActionListener buttonListener = ...

button.addActionListner(buttonListener);
password.addActionListener(buttonListener);
```

When enter is pressed in a `JTextField`, an action event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding an action listener to your textfield, like so.

```
JTextField field1 = new JTextField();

field1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //here is your method to continue
        continue();

        }

    });
```